# Breaking down UK in Shipping Methods

Tags: magento-1.9

we need to breakdown UK in shipping methods as a specific county as we offer free UK delivery except off mainland but Magento recognises everything including N. Ireland and Scottish Highlands which we have to charge a premium for.
Whats the best practise please?
Many thanks,
Chris

Comment: There are extensions like this one that apply shipping rates by post code http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension.html

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible with core Magento, so it boils down to "which shipping extension is the best" => opinion based. "Shopping list" questions are not a good fit for StackExchange Q&A
(see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad) -
you'll get better results at the Magento forums (http://community.magento.com)
or Reddit (http://www.reddit.com/r/Magento)

Answer (score 1):

This module will do the job http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension.html

And you may also be interested in this http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multi-flat-shipping.html

I have used both module on different UK stores and it is working fine

Answer (score 1):

[Matrix Rates](http://webshopapps.com/matrixrate-shipping-extension.html) is a long-standing popular extension for this type of thing although you may want the [premium version](http://webshopapps.com/premium-matrixrate-shipping-extension.html). Another extension worth considering is [Meanbee Shipping Rules](https://www.meanbee.com/magento-extensions/meanbee-shipping-rules.html)